How to Convert DynamoDB Map<String, AttributeValue> to Json with Capitalized type name
I am using Jackson's ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString() to convert an Map<String, AttributeValue>  to a JSON string. However, the types in the resulting JSON are all in lowercase. For example:
{
    "id": {
        "s": "88e5a5c2-a177-40b9-9cff-6a245f37f9e8",
        "n": null,
        "b": null,
        "m": null,
        "l": null,
        "bs": null,
        "ns": null,
        "ss": null,
        "null": null,
        "bool": null
    }
}

What I want to achieve is capitalized field names, like this:
{
    "id": {
        "S": "88e5a5c2-a177-40b9-9cff-6a245f37f9e8",
        "N": null,
        "B": null,
        ...
    }
}

is there a easy way?
